# Why does "deleted recent questions" not appear for users who have asked only one question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, deleted-posts-pages

A user asks a question.
It gets downvoted.(<strike>to oblivion</strike>)
And then gets deleted by a mod.

This question should then be accessible to the user in the **"deleted recent questions"** link but this doesn't happen.

If a user has asked *only one* question (which gets deleted) then this link goes missing.
Only after asking *another* question (which must not get deleted), is the user able to see that link.

Is this a bug <s>or a new-user-restriction</s>?

Comment: maybe this is to avoid yet another [meta-tag:plurals] bug report? "system says 'questions' but I have only one question" :)

Answer (score 7):

Strictly-speaking, a single deleted question would've always been accessible via the deleted recent questions link (assuming it was recently-asked)... But the link itself wasn't rendered due to being inadvertently placed in a conditional block predicated on there being more than 0 visible questions...

...And we never noticed this in testing because every employee who tested it has mod rights and thus always sees deleted questions listed anyway. We suck.

Amusingly, this bug also didn't show up in the mobile version of the site, which used a different template that puts the link in a separate section.

I created a sockpuppet yesterday and posted a terrible question, then deleted it. The problem was immediately obvious.

Kasra fixed this about 3 hours ago; this link should now *always* be visible, even if you've never asked any questions at all.